# How to retrieve source port with Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I've looked through the documentation and it doesn't look like there's support for lower level subjects such as sockets with Puppeteer. I'm trying to retrieve the source port of the request made with puppeteer, does someone have an idea of how that would be possible?

Here's obligatory current script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "False"});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('request', request => {
    console.log(request.url);
    });

  await page.goto('https://facebook.com');
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: In general, if you don't specify the port for a website address, port 80 is assumed. So unless *you* request specifically https://facebook.com:123 (and in this case you already know the port), the port will always be 80.

Comment: I meant the port that my local browser is using to make the request. The source port that it utilizes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is the `wsEndpoint` found [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserwsendpoint). This returns the location + port of where Chrome is listening for inbound protocol requests.